# Jqgrid border form with and without top pager

Tags: css, jqgrid

I have a Jqgrid with rounded border (top and bottom)
I achieved this by editiong the css file like this :

```
/* Corner radius */
.ui-corner-all,
.ui-corner-top,
.ui-corner-left,
.ui-corner-tl {
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
}
.ui-corner-all,
.ui-corner-top,
.ui-corner-right,
.ui-corner-tr {
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
}
.ui-corner-all,
.ui-corner-bottom,
.ui-corner-left,
.ui-corner-bl {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
}
.ui-corner-all,
.ui-corner-bottom,
.ui-corner-right,
.ui-corner-br {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
}
```

But if I enable the top pager I'm not able to get the top corners rounded (see picture).

My questions :

1. How to solve this and have the full table rounded with top pager enabled ?
2. Is it possible to have a dedicated border option to have only the top pager with a border (and the rest of the table would not have any border parameters)?
   I would like to give the top pager a separate / individual div border effect as if it wasn't part of the Jqgrid table.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you please share more code? That pager doesn't look like the regular one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do it:

```css
.ui-jqgrid-toppager {
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
}
```

If not, try for `.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-toppager`, but the above worked for me.

Comment: It actually works as axpected. Thanks. Since you seem to know the subject very well, How would I do to control the corners of the main table / frame ? I would like to have the top pager rounded on it's 4 corners (I achieve it thanks to your trick, I just added the bottom-left and bottom-right options) AND I also would like the main table with the 4 corners rounded at the same time. Any idea for this ? Anyway, thanks for helping me

Comment: Ok I found the answer, had to tweak the css with ".ui-jqgrid-hdiv"